# Partial View that represents my menu - VS2012 C#.NET MVC 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, partial-views

I have a Page model with a PagesContext.

I have a MenuController that I would like to include into the _Layout as a partial view. This _Menu includes the Page model:

```
@model IEnumerable<************.Models.Page>

<ul id="menu">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
    @foreach( var item in Model )
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink( item.Title, "Index", new { controller = "Menu", id = item.Id } )</li>                                
    }
</ul>
```

My MenuController creates an instance of the Page model:

```
public class MenuController : Controller
{
    private PagesContext db = new PagesContext();

    //
    // GET: /Menu/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Shared/_Menu", db.pages.ToList());
    }
}
```

and returns to the view an IEnumerable.

When I compile I get this error: ***Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***

This error is pointing to the beginning of my foreach? Any ideas?

Comment: That sounds like a run time error.. are you sure ToList() is returning items?

Comment: ahh mannn!! You're totally right! I'm a noob man! Cheers.. I forgot to add any pages.. DURRRR. I'll add a check there. Bro you saved me. I was going mad

Comment: Can I just do @if(model){... ?

Comment: Yeah you can.. `@if(Model==null)`.. might be better if it was in the Controller though :P

Comment: What do I return to an actionresult if I do not want it to go to the view? (or partial view in this case)?

Comment: You can return a JsonResult as well.. or a ActionResult that displays not found.. It depends on what you are doing

Comment: I'm trying to add a menu that displays dynamic pages that I create as an admin.. So obviously if there are no pages, I wouldn't need it to open up the menu view

Comment: Yeah.. you could create a View to handle that scenario and simply return that "NoPages" View.

Comment: How do you check if a dbcontext is empty?